# ReactJs firebase hosting deploy not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

Here Getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaE30.png) on the firebase url after deployment

- firebase init
- then select the Hosting
- What do you want to use as your public directory? build
- Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
- Overwrite? No
- Firebase intialization
- npm run build
- firebase deploy --only hosting

Note: I tried deployment using Heroku but failed because it was asking for a payment method using credit card
And also I had pushed code to GitHub before starting the deployment

Tried to use

- Firebase Login --reauth
- Firebase login
- Firebase init

Still getting the [same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxQYQ.png)

Comment: You initialized the Firebase project to deploy from the directory called "build", but you haven't listed any steps that puts the content you want to deploy in that directory, so you are certainly just deploying what gets put there automatically.